# Why is the Scanner not working properly in Java?

Tags: java

So I'm making a Client-Server program in java that is focused on changing data on the server. Here is the code for the client side:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            DatagramSocket socket=new DatagramSocket(4001);
            while(true){
                Scanner jin=new Scanner(System.in);
                String text=jin.nextLine();
                byte[] word=new byte[256];
                int command=Integer.parseInt(text);
                word=text.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket packet=new DatagramPacket(word, word.length, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 4000);
                socket.send(packet);

                if (command==0){
                    word=new byte[256];
                    packet=new DatagramPacket(word, word.length);
                    socket.receive(packet);
                    word=packet.getData();
                    System.out.println(new String(word));
                }

                else if (command==1){
                    word=new byte[256];
                    packet=new DatagramPacket(word, word.length);
                    socket.receive(packet);
                    System.out.println(new String(word));

                    int broj=jin.nextInt();
                    word=Integer.toString(broj).getBytes();
                    packet=new DatagramPacket(word, word.length, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 4000);
                    socket.send(packet);

                    word=new byte[256];
                    packet=new DatagramPacket(word, word.length);

                    socket.receive(packet);
                    System.out.println(new String(word));

                    new ClientHandler(socket).start();
                }

                else if(command==2){
                    word=new byte[256];
                    packet=new DatagramPacket(word, word.length);
                    socket.receive(packet);
                    System.out.println(new String(word));

                    jin=new Scanner(System.in);
                    int broj=Integer.parseInt(jin.next());

                    System.out.println("Test");
                    byte[] word1=Integer.toString(broj).getBytes();
                    System.out.println(new String(word1));
                    packet=new DatagramPacket(word1, word1.length, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 4000);
                    socket.send(packet);
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem lies in the if statement where:

```
else if (command==2)
```

After I enter a valid number the program doesn't move forward. After some debugging I found out that the problem lies in the Scanner or:

```
int broj=Integer.parseInt(jin.next());
```

The scanner doesn't register the inputted value and doesn't print "test" and the program gets stuck. Anyone know a solution?

Comment: Probably related (can't verify now): [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045)

Comment: Don't create multiple `Scanner` objects on `System.in`. Move the `Scanner jin=new Scanner(System.in);` line up before the `try` statement, then delete the `jin=new Scanner(System.in);` line down in the `else if(command==2){` block. Then follow the advice in the link provided by @Pshemo.

Comment: your code worked for me. I think the problem is with the client it keeps waiting for a response `socket.receive(packet)`, this blocks the thread until it gets a response.
think to move it to another thread, or make sure you app gets the response, I used Netcat to simulate the client using the following cmd `nc -u localhost 4001`.
https://imgur.com/a/LWb1RVu

Answer (score 0):

1. You're making Scanner more than once; this is no good. Have one scanner (create it **outside** the while loop).
2. Don't mix `nextLine` and any other next method. Either use only nextLine, or never use nextLine. If you want to grab 'the next string, until a newline' (versus 'the next string until a space, which is what `next()` normally does), set the delimiter: `scanner.useDelimiter("\r?\n")` immediately after making the scanner means that `next()` will grab entire lines now.

NB: You'll commonly see advice about throwing in an extra `nextLine` after a non-next call. This is extremely common, but bad advice. Fix the delimiter instead, as above.